# How do I express (A*B) + (~A*~B) using NAND gates?

Tags: boolean, boolean-logic, boolean-expression, boolean-operations, boolean-algebra

Currently running into an issue with needed to re-write the boolean expression (A*B) + (~A*~B) using only NAND gates. Any Ideas?

Comment: What issue did you run into? What have you tried so far?

Comment: @kaan I was able to make a circuit diagram for it but to re-write that diagram in terms of NAND gates had stumped me.